# how to create a child read only user of system user in oracle database

Tags: oracle, authentication, sqlplus

i have imported a employee database and by
`imp system/123 tables=departments,employees,titles,salaries,dept_emp,dept_manager  file=/oraclebackupEMPDEPT.dmp`
and then am trying to create a user just to read these values below is the following I tried

```
CREATE ROLE DEV_READONLY NOT IDENTIFIED; 
GRANT CONNECT TO DEV_READONLY;
GRANT create session, select any table, select any dictionary to DEV_READONLY;
create user candidate identified by 1234;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO candidate;
GRANT CONNECT TO candidate;
GRANT read on select any table, select any dictionary,EXECUTE, SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE, 
to candidate;
GRANT SELECT ON DEPARTMENTS, DEPT_EMP, DEPT_MANAGER, EMPLOYEES, SALARIES, TITLES TO 
candidate;
```

GRANT DEV_READONLY TO candidate;

`connect candidate/1234;`
connected
`select * from departments;`
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: `system` (or `sys`) shouldn't own any application tables. Create a regular schema for your application tables.

Comment: `GRANT SELECT ON ...` is useless if you have granted `select any table`

Comment: Also, why create a role and then grant all the same privileges to the user anyway? What's the point of the role?

Comment: And lastly, when you `select * from departments;`, what schema is departments in? you need to fully qualify the table name if it isn't in the `candidate` schema: e.g. `select * from app_schema.department;`